Why was the ignore tag button removed from the tag page?
Stack Exchange first removed the button from the tag page without ever saying they would during a completely unrelated experiment with tag information popups.
But the plan was always to "simplify" the tag page and strip the button from there.
But why?
I have already tried giving feedback for this missing button. And SE have just ignored engaging with it. Last it was dismissed because "the discussion moved elsewhere". A discussion that still completely omits talking about this and bringing it up would be considered off-topic giving SE freedom to never address this again.

I always thought the plan was to remove the "Ignore tag" button from the pop-up that you got when hovering over a tag. There was some convoluted, unconvincing explanation that they thought people were confusing it for a "close" button for the pop-up. That aside, I said at the time that I could understanding seeking to simplify the pop-up, and thus removing the "Ignore tag" button from the pop-up might be reasonable from a UX perspective (especially if optimizing for new users, rather than experienced ones). I cannot understand any reason why it would be removed from the full tag page.

@CodyGray yes, allegedly users were clicking "ignore tag" to close the popup. And removing the button was the "solution". Which is backwards. It comes off as a very weak justification to remove the button from the popup. If UX was really a consideration, they'd add an X button and see if that worked to alleviate the problem. Rather than remove it from 2/3 of the options and then claim that the removal was a success.

Hmm, this seems to only be here on Stack Overflow. Other sites seem to have the Ignore tag button next to the Watch tag button on the questions/tagged/ page. That does not seem to be logical to me.

@PeterJames the change to tag popups and tag pages is only on the main SO site. Of the things that are unclear about these changes, another one is whether this will be rolled out anywhere else and if so - when.

@VLAZ So the only way on the SO main site to ignore a tag is to click edit in the Ignored Tags box on the right sidebar and type the tag itself until the autocomplete selects the right tag. I cannot seem to find a way to just click to ignore a tag without typing.

@PeterJames correct, you cannot ignore it by clicking. There are actually two ways to ignore the tags (see footnote 3) right now and what you listed is one of those.

@VLAZ Well, after 10 minutes of searching for the other way, I feel that I have just gone on a wild goose chase. I am a little surprised. I know I haven't ignored anything on SO for quite some time, now I know why.

@PeterJames FWIW, the remaining way is more inconvenient than what you described. Not by much but certainly not worth pursuing as there is zero advantage. You still have to type in the tag name, anyway just from a different page which is several clicks away.

@VLAZ So the wild goose led me back to my users/tag-notifications/ page and I can also type tags that I want to ignore. I guess this is the second way that you were talking about. I think I found a bug on that page too. Now to see if it has been reported.

Btw, it’s also gone in the mockup for the new logged in home page. It’s like they’re slowly getting rid of it, one page at a time.

@KevinB the new logged in page has the "watched tags" widget which is also supposed to control ignored tags via the gear icon. No idea why I'd want to do it via a widget rather than clicking a button but it's what SE mocked up. Honestly, compared to that, the right sidebar thing is better. At least I don't have to jump through hoops go to a different page (assuming I'm at least on any page that shows the ignored tags. Of which there are more than the single homepage) and interact with a different thing just to add a tag as ignored.

It kind of does make sense to me, you shouldn't need to have to ignore tags frequently so you shouldn't need the feature front and center. BUT. right now you kind of do because the tag system sucks.

@Gimby yes, you shouldn't need to ignore tags often. However, SE have introduced friction by making it harder (you need to type in the exact tag. At least exact enough for the autocomplete, which is not often that simple) or you need to go find the tag and copy it. Which means going to the tag's page. And then you need to go to the text box that allows you to ignore it. But moreover, SE have reduced the visibility of this feature while keeping the same visibility for watching. Regardless of how often you're supposed to use this, they've yet to explain why they've done any of this.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think watched tags are delivered from the server by filtering the questions selected from the database and then ignored tags filter that list on the front end because we have the choice to hide the ignored tags or just grey them out. I personally hide my ignored tags. I wonder what other folk do?

@PeterJames for the homepage, the ignored tags are filtered server-side and you get a full set of questions (if the maximum is n, you get n). For the rest of the pages, if you have the the ignored tags set to hidden, then they are filtered client-side, so you will only see the remaining (if you have n set per page, you get n - ignored). I personally set ignored tags to be greyed out since I try to monitor for wrongly used tags. If I see a greyed out question, it's a call to action to remove the wrong tags (most of the time, at least).

I think they just want to foster the development of userscripts like SOX  joking aside, the site's question volume has been dropping significantly. I no longer need to negative-filter automatically.

My cynical side says this is was done to help promote collectives and make it harder for those sponsored tags to be ignored.

"You shouldn't need the ignore tags often"? I disagree. Who is able to read at the same time questions about backtrader, vml, clion, milvus, wtforms, apache-hudi, linear-regression, svg-animate, bruno, laragon? An omniscient developer interested by everything? Myself I have three watched tags: java, spring, apache-spark and HUNDREDS of ignored ones that I DON'T WAN'T TO READ THEM AT ALL, because I have no knowledge about them, or no interest. And I don't want their reading being imposed to me.
